# Select only whole words uiTextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, cpu-word, selection

I'm currently implementing a translation application. One that when a user selects a word from a UITextView the application translates to a different language.

I would like to restrict the options for selection to only whole words for example:

"Hello World" and not "Hello Wo"

Similar to the iOS Kindle application when defining words in the dictionary.

I have the UITextViewDelegate in my .h file.

I currently have in my .m:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView{
    [self translate];
}
```

and

```
- (void)translate {

    if(![[self.descriptionTextView selectedTextRange] isEmpty]) {

        NSString * selectedWord = [self.descriptionTextView textInRange:[self.descriptionTextView selectedTextRange]];

 ...
```

I then go on to convert this to an encodedString and fires off the Google Translate API. Is there a way to only select whole words from the UITextView? So that the selection increments in whole word chunks.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to force selection on fullword, but one way to go from there is to use regular expression to find the chunk of worlds that start by a ' ', end by a ' ', '.', '?' or other marks, and contains the selected text... you would then be sure to have only full words. I leave that though as a comment, in case a better answer shows up

Comment: You can always get the range of the selection, and check if range-1 = ' ' and range+1 = ' ' or punctuation ('.',',','!' etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can add yourself as the `inputDelegate` of the text field and implement `selectionDidChange:`. When the selection changes you can use `positionWithinRange:atCharacterOffset:` to investigate around the selected range for white space. Once you've found your desired range you can update the `selectedTextRange`.